# Select all checkboxes using jquery issue and not working function

Tags: jquery, select, checkbox

First: How can I select all checkboxes with specified ID?

Second:

I got:

```
<a href="javascript://" id="chkbox:all">Click to select all of the checkboxes</a>
```

And then at the top of the script I'm using this:

```
$(function () {
 $('#chkbox:all').click(function () {
  alert(1);
 });
});
```

And `alert` doesn't appear on my screen - mean that function is not running - why it happends?

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. There's no selector `:all` and you can't use colons in IDs--take that out
2. IDs must be unique. You can't have 2 or more elements with the same ID.

You'll need to use another strategy for finding all the checkboxes. Something like this:

```
$('input:checkbox').click( /* ... */ );
```

Or add a class to all the checkboxes and do this:

```
$('input.yourclass:checkbox').click( /* ... */ );
```

If you want to click on a link and have that check all the boxes, try this:

```
// check on all the checks
$('#all-link-id').click(function(){ 
  $('input.yourclass:checkbox').attr('checked', true);
});

// check off all the checks
$('#none-link-id').click(function(){ 
  $('input.yourclass:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
});
```

Comment: I dont want to click on the checkbox, to check all boxes. I want to click on the href, and then all checkboxes should be checked/unchecked.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to set more than 1 checkbox with the same ID, you should be using a class instead, since IDs are supposed to be unique identifiers.

Also, don't use ":all" as part of your identifiers, since jQuery might think you want to use a selector... try to change that and your code should work :)