# check all checkbox with hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I add a checkbox that can check all the checkboxes if it's checked?

How can I add show/hide functionality to the "check all" checkbox. 
The submit button also need to be showed if the check all checkbox is checked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var $submit = $("#submit_prog").hide(),
    $cbs = $('input[name="prog"]').click(function() {
        $submit.toggle( $cbs.is(":checked") );
    });

});

<input type="checkbox" name="?" value="?">  // check all checkbox

<input type="checkbox" name="prog" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="prog" value="2">

<input type="submit" id="submit_prog" value='Submit' />
```

Comment: Have you tried this?: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/7720869/1207958](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7720869/1207958)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. assumption id of select all chckbox is selall.
2. create a class for all the check box you want to select using select all

```
$('#selall').click(function(event) {   
    if(this.checked) {
        // Iterate each checkbox
        $('.yourchckbox').each(function() {
            this.checked = true;                        
        });
        $('#submit_prog').show();
    }
    else { 
    $('.yourchckbox').each(function() 
    { this.checked = false; }); 
    $('#submit_prog').hide()
    }
});
  $('.yourchckbox').click(function(event) { 
   if(!(this.checked)) {
   $('#selall').prop('checked', false);   
   }

  });
```

Comment: what about the submit button? It's still hidden when I check the check all checkbox.

Comment: edited my answer. sorry missed the submit part while reading the question.

Comment: Now it works. Could you please ad the function that if I at least uncheck one of the checkbox values the check all checkbox will be unchecked. Thanks.

Comment: When I uncheck one of the checkboxes the "check all" is not unchecked.

Answer (score 1):

Give the select all check box an id, say `selectall` then

```
$('#selectall').click(function(){
    if (this.checked){
        $('input[name="prog"]').prop('checked', true);
        $submit.toggle( true );
    }
});
```

if you want the checkboxes to be unselected if the select all in unselected

```
$('#selectall').click(function(){
    $('input[name="prog"]').prop('checked', this.checked);
    $submit.toggle( this.checked);
});
```

```
$cbs = $('input[name="prog"]').click(function() {
    $submit.toggle( $cbs.filter(':checked').length == 0 );
    if (!this.checked) $('#selectall').prop('checked', false);
});
```

Comment: But you can also click manually on `name="prog"`, and then `$submit` visibility will be wrong.

Comment: So there is an option, that no checkboxes will be `:checked` and you will see `$submit`. That's a bug.

Comment: If check all is checked I need it to be unchecked if I at least uncheck one checkbox

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('input:checkbox[name!="prog"]').click(function(){
     $('input:checkbox[name="prog"]').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'))
})
```

Or if you can change checkbox id to `selall`

```
$('#selall').click(function(){
     $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'))
})
```

Comment: the submit button is still hidden

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple.

lets name this checkbox `<input type="checkbox" name="check_all" value="1">`

And now add event:

```
$('input[name="check_all"]').click( function() {
    if( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
        $('input[name="prog"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
    } else {
        $('input[name="prog"]').removeAttr('checked');
    }

    $('input[name="prog"]:eq(0)').change(); //firing event which we will catch
});
```

Then we should check if all `input[name="prog"]` are checked:

```
$('input[name="prog"]').change( function() {
    if( $('input[name="prog"]:not(:checked)').length ) {
        $('#submit_prog').hide();
    } else {
        $('#submit_prog').show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Use properties instead of attributes to manipulate checkbox state

Answer (score 0):

select all checkboxes on `#all` check and check `#all` when all checkboxes are checked

```
 <SCRIPT language="javascript">
    $(function(){

        $("#all").click(function () {
              $('.one').attr('checked', this.checked);
     if (this.checked) {$('#submit_prog').hide();}
(this.checked)?$('#submit_prog').show():$('#submit_prog').hide();
        });

        $(".one").click(function(){

            if($(".one").length == $(".one:checked").length) {
                $("#all").attr("checked", "checked");
                $('#submit_prog').show();
            } else {
                $("#all").removeAttr("checked");
$('#submit_prog').hide();
            }

        });
    });
    </SCRIPT>
```

Change id and class of checkboxes

```
<input type="checkbox" id="all" >  // check all checkbox

<input type="checkbox" name="prog" class="one" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="prog" class="one" value="2">
```

Comment: the check all only work once and the submit button is still hidden.

Comment: Use properties instead of attributes to manipulate checkbox state

Comment: Hmm still only checkmark all the checkboxes once. But the show/hide function works fine.